# How to rotate clockwise or counterclockwise specific elements within an $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

Given a matrix $A_{\,3 \times 3}$, it is possible that there exist 8 functions or linear transformations such that they modify the matrix in the following way:

\begin{align} A = \begin{pmatrix} x       & y      & a_{13} \\ z       & w      & a_{23} \\ a_{31}  & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix} \qquad ; \qquad & T_{A-} \, (A) \ = \ \begin{pmatrix} z       & x      & a_{13} \\ w       & y      & a_{23} \\ a_{31}  & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix} \end{align}

Where $T_A$ rotates the elemets $a_{11}, \ a_{12},\  a_{21},\  a_{22}$, $\ $   $T_B$ rotates $a_{12}, \ a_{13}, \ a_{22}, \ a_{23}$, and so on. Also, the "-" rotates thoose elements clockwise, and the "+" sign, counterclockwise.

This can also be visualised
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMv0I.png).

So, I wanted to ask, how would these transformations look like? I'm new to linear algebra and I tried to implement them with matrix multiplications but I didn't succeed  that's why I wanted to ask for help on this problem.

The idea for this question came to me when I saw the problem of the *Number Rotation Puzzle*, I wanted to see if there is a way to represent the problem in linear algebra.

And that's about it, I will be attentive to any recommendations or comments.

Thank you so much for the help! Have a nice day.

Comment: The mapping $A\mapsto T(A)$  is a linear transformation of the space $\Bbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, so you can surely think of it like that. Essentially you will then think of a $3\times3$ matrix as a vector with $9$ components, and check out what the transformation does to each of the nine matrices in a basis.

Comment: (cont'd) However, it is impossible to, for example, find matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $T(A)=PAQ$ holds for all the matrices $A$. This is because $T$ itself is invertible, and hence $P$ and $Q$ would need to be invertible as well. But $T$ may map an invertible $A$ into a non-invertible matrix, when $\det (PAQ)=0$ but $\det A\neq0$. Obviously impossible.

Comment: (cont'd) So to give a more precise answer, you would need to describe what kind of linear transformation are you looking for? We can describe these transformations by a linear combination of more complicated matrix products (that simply extract individual matrix entries out of $A$, move them, and recombine.